# How can I warm my feet in winter without shoes and socks?

Tags: personal-care, winter

In winter how can I warm my feet without using of shoes and socks? Because I can't use shoes dua to a injure in my feet . So what should I do for warming my feet?

Comment: This depends on where you are and what resources you have available. Are you indoors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are electrically heated feet warmers. They look like giant boots, wide enough to put two feet in. In themselves these are enough to keep your feet from going cold, but when you use the heater you will get them warm sooner.

Alternatively, you can put one foot or both in a sleeping bag and also put in a warm water bottle or an other heater which is safe to use in the bag and near your skin.
In the old days, they would heat a brick or stone in, over or near the fire, wrap that in cloth before using and put it in a bed before going to sleep. If you do not have a hot water bottle, you could copy that old example.

To prevent your foot getting cold (again) keep it wrapped in fabric and put an wind proof layer on the outside.

And it might be warmer to keep your leg/foot off the floor when sitting down. Drafts are often along the floor and are almost always cold.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options.

1. If you have an electric hair dryer, you can blow that hot air on your feet for 20-30 seconds.  That should warm them up.
2. Fill a bucket, large bowl, or pot with hot water. Put your feet in it until they are warm. (Be sure to dry them off afterwards!)